# How to remove everything except html tag and content of this HTML tag in notepad++?

Tags: html, notepad++

I open an HTML page in Notepad++.

The html page has a lot of things, but especially this tag:

```
<div id="issue_content">CONTENT</div>
```

I’d like to remove everything from the html file except
this tag and its content :

```
<div id="issue_content">CONTENT</div>
```

Example of file:

```
<p>ewrfefsd</p>
<div id="issue_content">CONTENT</div>
<p>ewrfefsd</p>
</html>
```

After deleting, the contents of the file should look like this:

```
<div id="issue_content">CONTENT</div>
```

I try to use regular expression: 
`(<div id=\"issue_content\">)(.*?)(<\/div>)(.*?)`
,
but this regular expression remove only tag `<div id="issue_content">CONTENT</div>` and  content of this tag

Comment: Why don't you create a new string with that content, since that's all you're interested in? You already have the match value.

Comment: I need to remove unnecessary content in 3000 html files. 
The content in the <div id = "issue_content"> DIFFERENT CONTENT </ div> tag is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should do what you want. Make sure you check the `. matches newline` box on the `Replace` tab, and position the cursor at the beginning of the document.

```
^.*?(<div[^>]*id="issue_content">.*?<\/div>).*$
```

Replace with `\1`.

Note that this code will only work if there are no other `<div>` tags nested within the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your Regex to the following: The idea is that it matches everything, but creates a `Match` `Group`, containing the string you want, that you can use to replace everything with your `Group`:

This is the regex:

```
/[\s\S]*?(<div id=\"issue_content\">[^>]+>)[\s\S]+/
```

It matches everything at start upto the string, you want, then it creates a Group with your string, and finally matches everything after that.

When replacing, you replace with Group 1:

```
$1
```

Now you only have your string.

Comment: /[\s\S]*?(<div id=\"issue_content\">[^>]+>)[\s\S]+/   - don't work (((

Comment: @alexbever: Remove delimiters

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where `$str` is your HTML content variable.

```
preg_match('/<div id="issue_content">(.*)<\/div>/i', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```